# adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory in UILabel with attributed text

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I thought I would save others hours of debugging and say that setting `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` to true has no affect on labels you set the `attributedText` value of (at least in tableview cell labels).

Luckily the solution is to set the font on the attributed string yourself. I wrote a small utility extension:

```
public extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    public func setFont(_ font: UIFont) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: font, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count))

        return self
    }
}
```

Where you set the attributedText property you would call

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

var myAttributedString: NSAttributedString = .....

myLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: myAttributedString).setFont(myLabel.font)
```

Comment: Thanks, Please answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public extension NSMutableAttributedString {
public func setFont(_ font: UIFont) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: font, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count))

    return self
}
```

}